# DebugActiveProcess crash

Tags: c#, windows, api, debugging

I'm trying to debug a child process while it's in a suspended state. The problem is that when I attempt to do that, the application doesn't start (it starts but exits instantly). That helps against reverse engineering, but however I can't manage doing it.

```
static void DebuggingTest(PROCESS_INFORMATION pi, int imageBase, int sizeOfHeaders)
{
    int oldProtection = 0;
    const uint STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION = 0x80000001;
    const int DBG_CONTINUE = 0x00010002;
    DEBUG_EVENT evt = new DEBUG_EVENT();
    if (!DebugActiveProcess(Convert.ToInt32(pi.dwProcessId)))
        throw new Win32Exception();
    else
        MessageBox.Show(pi.dwProcessId + " process is being debugged.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    while (true)
    {
        if (!WaitForDebugEvent(out evt, -1))
            throw new Win32Exception();
        else
            MessageBox.Show("WaitForDebugEvent executed.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        switch (evt.dwDebugEventCode)
        {
            case DebugEventType.CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
                //if (!VirtualProtectEx(pi.hProcess, imageBase, sizeOfHeaders, 320, ref oldProtection))
                //  throw new Exception();
                ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
                MessageBox.Show("CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT executed.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
            case DebugEventType.EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
                if (evt.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION)
                {
                    if (!VirtualProtectEx(pi.hProcess, imageBase, sizeOfHeaders, 320, ref oldProtection))
                        throw new Exception();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT executed.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
            case DebugEventType.EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
                if (!DebugActiveProcessStop(Convert.ToInt32(pi.dwProcessId)))
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                if (!TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0))
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                MessageBox.Show("EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT executed.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
            case DebugEventType.LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
                if (CloseHandle(evt.LoadDll.hFile))
                    MessageBox.Show("CloseHandle executed.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
        }

        if (ContinueDebugEvent(evt.dwProcessId, evt.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE))
            MessageBox.Show("Last ContinueDebugEvent executed.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

**Edit: VirtualProtectEx calls are failing, they are the actual problem. If I comment their lines, the application executes. Also it is lagging, probably because of the debugging loop. Is there a solution for it?**

**Edit2: I edited the code as you suggested me, apart from DEBUG_PROCESS, because it stops the whole process, I can't even kill it through Task Manager, the only way to kill it, is to restart PC. Perhaps, I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. So the order the messageboxes appear: DebugActiveProcess executed -> WaitForDebugEvent executed -> CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT executed -> Last ContinueDebugEvent executed. Then Wait... -> CloseHandle -> ContinueDebug...**

Comment: if you yourself create process by [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) you need use [`DEBUG_PROCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of call `DebugActiveProcess`

Comment: Can you give me an example code,

Comment: example of what ? and i not wrote on *c#*. at first you not show your debugging loop - how minimum basic details, which event and how you handle. are you got some debug messages ? you must even if process crash. `DebugActiveProcess` create additional thread in process - `DbgUiRemoteBreakIn` - so process begin itialize not in it main thread but on this thread. say on *xp* this will be process intit fail always. on win10 generally must work correct , if you correct process debug events

Comment: Sorry, I edited my initial question.

Comment: because you use flag `CREATE_SUSPENDED` - and not resume thread. use only `DEBUG_PROCESS` flag without `CREATE_SUSPENDED`. and for kill debugging process - you need kill debugger, but not restart pc

Comment: `DebugActiveProcess` - **not use it**

Comment: But somehow I have to manage both CREATE_SUSPENDED + DEBUG_PROCESS

Comment: for what you `CREATE_SUSPENDED` ??? **remove** it. use only `DEBUG_PROCESS`

Comment: ok, last time explain -  remove `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag ,`ResumeThread(pi.hThread);` and `DebugActiveProcess` use **only** `DEBUG_PROCESS` and all will be work just fine

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will accept your answer. Got it working, but with DebugActiveProcess instead of DEBUG_PROCESS.

Comment: but again - you not need use `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and `DebugActiveProcess` - but `DEBUG_PROCESS` **without** `CREATE_SUSPENDED` - are you understand this ? understand why `CREATE_SUSPENDED` absolute senseless here ?

Comment: because I can't change the headers, if it's not suspended

Comment: you **still nothing understand** - you **not need** suspend process. when you debug it. all debugging messages is sent **synchronous**. when you got any debug message - all process is suspended and wait for your response. so again - you **NOT NEED SUSPEND** process in this case. it is nonsense. you need `DEBUG_PROCESS` flag without `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and in `"CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` you can change headers or any another task. at this point process not begin execute in user mode yet and wait for your response (ContinueDebugEvent call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) when you want debug process created via [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) set the [`DEBUG_PROCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) in *dwCreationFlags*

2) never call `DebugActiveProcess` in this case - this api internal create remote thread in process - `DbgUiRemoteBreakIn` - so process begin initialize not in it main thread but on this thread. say on xp this cause process initialization fail always. latter (begin form win7 ?) this fixed.

3) `ContinueDebugEvent` need call **always**, after every debug event. after `EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` - **also** - need understand that this message send to you last thread in process when it exited. and he wait for your call `ContinueDebugEvent` - process still alive and not terminated when you got `EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` - so you must have one common call to `ContinueDebugEvent` after *swith*

4) what you try todo with `VirtualProtectEx` must make infinite `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` exceptions. so even not look more - main logic of "protection" is invalid

5) handle `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` is **mandatory** - you must close handle  ([hFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680351(v=vs.85).aspx) to the loaded DLL)

6) on `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` you also must close handle to file

---

7) when we call `CreateProcess` with `DEBUG_PROCESS` flag - use the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` - **absolutely senseless** - for what ?? usually this flag used for do some task with process, before it thread begin execute in user mode and after this call `ResumeThread`. but when we use `DEBUG_PROCESS` initial thread in process, when it begin execute (yet in kernel mode) send to us `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` and wait for reply (until debugger not call `ContinueDebugEvent`. as result all special task with process we can done in `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` handler. misunderstandings how windows work internal leads to gross errors

Comment: DEBUG_PROCESS freezes the process, you can't kill it, nothing executes, the only way to terminate the process is to restart PC. The only thing that works is by DebugActiveProcess. Therefore, I added LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT with CloseHandle(evt.LoadDll.hFile); and moved ContinueDebugEvent below the switch

Comment: @Nox - you absolute mistake. `DEBUG_PROCESS` work just fine and nothing freeze - your else one error that you create process in **suspended** state and call `ResumeThread` only in `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` - but you never got it because thread is suspended. simply create process without `CREATE_SUSPENDED`. and not call `ResumeThread(pi.hThread);` of course. especially from debug event, but not **before** wait on this events

Comment: @Nox - `restart PC` this is funny - simply kill debugger not try ?

Comment: Well it's not possible to change the suspended state, because what my application does. It executes code.

Comment: @Nox - `not possible to change the suspended state` ?!?! simply call CreateProcess without `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag. what is not possible ???